# How can I get React Native to put JS bundle in Share Extension when compiling for Release?

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, reactjs, react-native

I can load via `jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true"];` when developing, but using `jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];` in Extension doesn't work by default.

I can get the file from main app's bundle through getting parent directory of parent directory but prob. not the best way to ensure it works long-term...

Answer (score 2):

Ok it's simple enough -- I just copied `Bundle React Native code and images` in Build Phases from app into Extension's Build Phases.  It does double the work, so there's prob. a way to get it to reuse what it did before in the extension, but this works for me for now.